# How do I install Broadcom wireless adapter and how do I find out which Broadcom I have?

Tags: broadcom

A while back, when first playing around with Ubuntu, I tried installing on Aspire 5517 laptop. I got the information to find out what adapter I had and how to modify Ubuntu to see it. I am now trying again to convert this laptop but have lost all that information. Any and all information will help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So to find the chip installed you need to open a terminal and place this command `lspci`. It will give you a long list of all devices your computer uses.

e.g.

```
    03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
```

or try this:

`sudo lshw -C network`

With this information I googled and found immediately a Linux driver. I am not sure, if this also is available for your Chip, but give it a try.

When you already transform your notebook completely, why not try a normal reinstall? The installing routines will find themselves a fitting driver. I got problems back in the days of 2010 but recent Ubuntu releases are very good regarding the driver selection.

Someone else had a similar problem, of course ;-) Google is our friend.
[Acer Aspire 5517 / Broadcom BCM4312](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2206217)